# Windows 10 WSL bash change starting directory

Tags: windows-10, bash, .bash-profile, wsl2

When I launch bash on Windows, it always starts in the directory that it is launched from [`/mnt/c/Users/myuser`], however I would like it to launch in the WSL `$HOME` directory [`~`].

How do I specify the start directory, preferably in a non-permanent way, similar to:

```
bash --startdir ~
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `cd ~` at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file, and after loading the user profile, the directory will be changed to `$HOME`.

If `$HOME` is wrongly configured, you can edit it in `/etc/passwd` by issuing:

```
usermod -d /<newhome>/<username> <username>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works but I meant something different. I would like to pass a parameter when opening bash to be able to launch bash in the ~ directory when this is desired. I just updated the post to make it more clear :)